# python loop and print string with variables

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop this 10 times and change all the the numbers on each line.

```
<li>1. <a href='/some/url/index.php?member=_MEMBER_1_'>_MEMBER_1_DESC_ (_MEMBER_1_UNI_IN_) </a></li>
```

I tried it with range function but dont know how to change the digits.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in range(5):
print  ("<li> %d. <a href='/some/url/index.php?member=_MEMBER_%d_'>_MEMBER_%d_DESC_ (_MEMBER_%d_UNI_IN_) </a></li>") % i
```

maybe I have to set a regex for the line and then filter on numbers. but then how to change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do:

```
for i in range(5):
    print  ("<li> %d. <a href='/some/url/index.php?member=_MEMBER_%d_'>_MEMBER_1_DESC_ (_MEMBER_%d_UNI_IN_) </a></li>") % **(i, i, i)**
```

Note the 3 times that I put the "i" variable.

And if you want to make the loop 10 times, assuming you need number from 1 to 10, you should use:
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print ...

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
>>> "%d%d%d" % 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> "%d%d%d" % (1,1,1)
'111'
```

You need to specify a number for *each* `'%d'` in your string.

Note that you can get around this if you use the dictionary form:

```
>>> "%(val)s%(val)s%(val)s" % {'val': 1}
'111'
```

But these days I would prefer `.format`:

```
>>> '{0}{0}{0}'.format(1)
'111'
```

In your case:

```
print ("<li> {0}. <a href='/some/url/index.php?member=_MEMBER_{0}_'>_MEMBER_{0}_DESC_ (_MEMBER_{0}_UNI_IN_) </a></li>").format(i)
```